# trying to display feed, i can see mine, but other users cant see theirs?

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api, feed

i am trying to develop my first app on facebook which will display a users feed, i aim to filter out the array to display only certain posts from certain apps, but have run into a little problem. i can seem to see my feeds array but other users cant see theirs, i think it may be something to do with permissions or access tokens, but since im new to this, i dont really know.

here is the code i have at the moment:

```
 <?php
require('src/facebook.php');

   $app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
   $app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));



//Facebook Authentication part
$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'scope'         => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,read_stream'
    )
);
$user       = $facebook->getUser();


if ($user) {
  try {

   // $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $user_feed = $facebook->api('/'.$user.'/feed?access_token='.$facebook->getAccessToken().'');
    //$user_home = $facebook->api('/'.$user.'/home');
    //$user_home = $facebook->api('/'.$user.'/apprequests?access_token='.$facebook->getAccessToken().'');

    //echo $user_profile['name'];

    echo "<pre>";
    foreach($user_feed['data'] as $feed){
   // print_r ($user_home);
    print_r ($feed);
    print_r (''.$feed['link'].'<br>');
    //print_r ($user_home);
  }
    echo "</pre>";

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
}

if (!$user) {
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = ".$loginUrl."</script>";
     exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What permissions are you asking the users for? you need the read_stream permission from a user to access their feed

Comment: 'scope' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,read_stream'

Comment: And each of the users whose feeds you're trying to access has granted those permissions? (you can check with a call to /me/permissions)

Comment: users dont seem to be prompt for permission either. me/permissions prints Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [installed] => 1 [bookmarked] => 1 ) ) )    im testing with my own account and partners account